# To copy Data from google Groups and pasting that data to Google Sheets using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, automation

I've sheet available on google group on daily basis by different users, and I need to import that sheet and append that sheet data to Google sheets using python coding.
Is there any way by which I can fetch the data from google group and paste that in Google sheet?
need to automate the process of copying data from Google groups and then pasting it to Google sheet from each each users data on daily basis.

Comment: Yes. Use the API

Comment: @Madhurjya can you suggest some?

Comment: I think there is a python library for Google APIs.